# How to convert multiple cells to display as hyperlinks

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I have a column with over 500,000 characters like below:

```
my_Curves/drCurve_tt025463a.pdf
```

I want to convert them to a hyperlink. When I do the following:

```
=HYPERLINK("my_Curves/drCurve_tt025463a.pdf",[myname])
```

and I try to apply it on all cells, it will just copy the same name and the same pdf file will show up.

I also tried this:

```
=hyperlink(C:\Users\admin\Desktop\target\my_Curves\drCurve_tt025463a.pdf,[myname])
```

but it did not work either.

Can someone guide me how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your text is in column A starying at A1 and values to [myname] are in column B you could do this in C1:

```
=hyperlink(A1,B1)
```

Then you can doubleclick to the rectangle in the lower right corner of the cell to copy until the end of the column

Comment: is there anyway to remove those that they don't have any link for the hyperlink but they have names?

Comment: yes, but you would need to distinguish your data someone as to which ones are just names and which ones are path.

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful to edit your question and add a few lines of your data. It's difficult to help without seeing the format.